# Do elements hidden by overflow still get rendered?

Tags: css, rendering, overflow, hidden

Working on a render-heavy layout and before I make some big changes–I want to be sure that elements that are hidden by overflow:hidden on their parent container are NOT actually painted by the browser.

Anyone have some insight/ experience/ articles with this?

Answer (score 0):

"overflow: hidden" has a painting performance cost. Google says that. The answer is yes, it is actuallt painted by the browser.

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo, can't seem to find anything as you have. Would you mind posting for future reference?